# how to create ODBC Data source for a SQL Server 2008 on another machine?

Tags: sql-server

I was able to create an ODBC Data Source locally for my SQL Server 2008. Now I moved to anohter machine and want to connect from the new machine to that SQL Server 2008.

I know by default the SQL Server 2008 will not listen for the remote connection. I have enabled its Browser and TCP/IP.

Error window is like this: [alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/152679b8b6.jpg](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/152679b8b6.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Did you ensure that the SQL Server 2008 Browser service is running on the server?

Comment: I think so. I restarted the service and also the machine and checked the status of the Browser. It is running.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a firewall between the 2 machines?

If so, you will need to allow the applicable protocol and port.